# How to check if property is undefined using LINQ query for MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

To check whether a property is `null` using LINQ for MongoDB, we can write

```
var query = collection
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.MyProperty == null);
```

But in MongoDB, `null` and `undefined` are different from each other. How can we test using LINQ(!) whether a property is (or is not) undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with as a workaround, but perhaps there is a better solution:

```
var filter = Builders<MyType>.Filter.Exists(
    x => x.MyProperty, false);

var query = collection
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => filter.Inject() && ...)
```